# ubicacion Flow con kotlin

Tags: kotlin, servicio, geolocalización

Hola necesito enviar mi ubicación cada minuto, aun cuando el usuario cierre la aplicación, entonces leí que debería de hacer un service, trate de hacer el service pero no se ejecutaba cada minuto mi método de envió , entonces leí que debería implementar los flow, igual ya trate de implementar algo así..

```
  val counter: Flow<Int> = channelFlow {
    while (true) {
     trySend( sendData(id_persona))
        delay(10000)
    }
}
```

La primera vez que se ejecuta o se abre la app lo hace "bien" si manda la ubicacion cada minuto, sin embargo si vuelvo abrir la aplicación, como que se crea n cantidad de flows(dependiendo que tantas veces abra la app) por asi decirlo, y entonces al mismo tiempo manda n cantidad de ubicaciones

Ya intente cerrar el servicio de la siguiente manera

```
override fun onStartCommand(intencion: Intent?, flags: Int, idArranque: Int): Int {
    if (intencion != null) {
        val action: String? = intencion.getAction();
        if(action!=null)
            when (action) {
                ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
                    startForegroundService()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Foreground service is started.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
                ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
                    stopForegroundService()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Foreground service is stopped.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
    }
   return super.onStartCommand(intencion, flags, idArranque);
   // return START_STICKY;//siempre se vuelva a generar el servicio aunque el sistema mate el servicio
}
```

donde stopForegroundService() tiene

```
private fun stopForegroundService() {
    stopSelf()

}
```

pero aun así se envía n cantidad de ubicaciones al mismo tiempo sin dejar que pase el minuto